# Es posible mostrar en el navegador un elemento vacio de xml con css

Tags: css, xml

Tengo este codigo xml por ejemplo:

```
<br>
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
    <raiz>
       <activo/>
    </raiz>
<br>
```

y me gustaría mostrar la palabra activo en el navegador aplicándole css.

Comment: ¿Te refieres a validar el xml con CSS?

Comment: No lo que querría es que al aplicar css a un xml me mostrara el elemento vacío en el navegador

Comment: CSS no te puede validar si un XML está vacío o no. De hecho, si intentas mostrar el XML directamente en el HTML te aparecerán solamente los campos que estén rellenos (sin etiquetas, solo su contenido). No sé si es lo que estás buscando.

Comment: A ver si he entendido bien: ¿Quieres que en pantalla solo salgan las etiquetas que esten vacias? Eso con CSS soio no lo puedes hacer, vas a necesitar JavaScript o algo similar.

Comment: vale Gracias provare con javaScript

Comment: Talvés es lo que necesitas: `activo {
   display: block; background-color: black;
   margin: 10px 0;
}'

Comment: Pero eso se aplicaría al contenido y como es una etiqueta vacía no sale nada

Comment: Yo quiero que saque la palaba activo de la etiqueta

Comment: se me ocurre ¿No sería posible poner un texto por defecto a un elemento de XML con CSS ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con CSS, se puede seleccionar los elementos `activo` vacíos: `active:empty` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty). Por ejemplo, la regla

```
activo:empty {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

hace que el navegador ponga un borde por los elementos `activo` que no tienen contenido (excepto commentarios).

Además se puede insertar contenido en estos elementos con el selector `activo:empty::before`, por ejemplo:

```
activo:empty::before {
    content: 'empty';
}
```

```css
raiz, activo {
 display: block;
}
activo:empty {
 border: 1px solid red;
}
activo:empty::before {
 content: 'empty';
}
```

```html
<raiz>
 <activo></activo>
 <activo>contenido</activo>
</raiz>
```

Comment: Perfecto me viene muy bien porque tengo el mismo elemento con contenido también y lo habia tenido que renombrar

Answer (score 0):

Me auto respondo ya está solucionado añadiendo al CSS `activo:before {
content: "Activo"; 
}`